# Close a content type form in a modal popup and avoid redirection to the created node page

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I have a content type reference on a user page. On clicking the add content button it opens as modal popup with the node form. Post filling the form on submission the page redirects and goes to the node created page.

Using this to open the form in pop up
`<p><a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal" href="/node/add/article">Add New Article</a></p>`

How can i avoid the following - **On form submission the pop up should close and the page should not redirect and the data should be added to article content type. Need to have Ajax form submit.**